# Print distinct characters in a string with count

Tags: c#, linq

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string s = "Stack Overflows";

        var x = from c in s.ToLower()
                group c by c into a
                select new { a.Key, Count = a.Count() };
        Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(x));

        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

Output is system.linq.Enumable+

```
i want output like a 2 g 1 s 1 p 2 r 1
```

Comment: I don't see any `g` and `p` in your string. And there is only one `a`. And two `s`.

Comment: i just gave the example  i want output like s 2 t 1 a 1 c 1 k 1 O 2 v1 e 1 ....... etc like this

Answer (score 4):

```
Console.WriteLine(String.Join(" ", x.Select(y=>y.Key + " " + y.Count)));
```

or using lambda syntax

```
string s = "Stack Overflows";
Console.WriteLine(String.Join(" ", s.GroupBy(c => c)
                                    .Select(g => g.Key + " " + g.Count())));
```

Comment: @L.B , I have modified your code, Please see my answer . Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can also use aggregate function like this:

```
Console.WriteLine(x.Select(y => String.Format("{0} {1}", y.Key, y.Count)).Aggregate((y, z) => y + String.Format(" {0}", z)));
```

[Aggregate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.linq.enumerable.aggregate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) function can be used for any types (not only strings)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code instead of your code, I have modified @L.B code

```
string s = "Stack Overflows";    
 var x = String.Join("", (from c in s.ToLower()
         group c by c into a 
         select new { a.Key, Count = a.Count() }).Select(y => y.Key + " " + y.Count));
```